# SPA template is missing from VS12 premium

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, single-page-application

I have Visual Studio 2012 Premium installed.  When I try to create an `SPA Application` in `MVC 4`, its template is not available there, as seen in the screenshot below.  How do I add the template?

[image: Screenshot of Project Creation page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update your `Visual Studio 2012 Premium`, in the update, all these new featured are added like `Single Page Application`, `Facebook Application` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Which updates do you have installed?  According to the [ASP.NET documentation,](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/introduction/knockoutjs-template) you have to install the ASP.NET Web Tools 2012.2 Update, which can be [found here.](http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx?command=getinstallerredirect&appid=ASPDOTNETandWebTools2012_2)

The documentation also has step-by-step instructions stating how to make an SPA if it's already installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Jumpstart and learn **SPA application** in **VS professional 2012**, You can install HotTowel SPA

1. Create Empy Asp.net MVC project
2. Installing via the NuGet Package
3. Open Nuget Manage Console & Type the below command

> Install-Package HotTowel

1. After succesfully installing run the project
2. while running the project if you get the below error. 
   The type initializer for 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration' threw an exception.
3. Kindly

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -IncludePrerelease

For more information of this template click the below links
http://www.johnpapa.net/hottowel/